# How to make the header responsive?

Tags: html, css

The header works perfectly in my laptop , when the browser screen is maximised. But when the browser screen is resized , it is not responsive, the post button disappears and search button changes its alignment and when checked for mobile responsiveness, it is totally misplaced.

```css
.navbar-fixed-top{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px red;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px red;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px red;
    background: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.1)
}

#logo{
 margin-top: -5px;
}

/*Search field*/
#search{
        
        font: 13px 'Lucida sans', Arial, Helvetica;
        color: #eee;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
#search a {
        color: #ccc;
    }
    
    /*-------------------------------------*/
    
    .cf:before, .cf:after{
      content:"";
      display:table;
    }
    
    .cf:after{
      clear:both;
    }

    .cf{
      zoom:1;
    }

    /*-------------------------------------*/ 
    
    .form-wrapper{
        height :60px;
    }
    
    .form-wrapper input {
        width: 500px;
        height: 40px;
        padding: 10px 5px;
        float: left;    
        font: bold 15px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
        border: 0;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 150px;
        background: #eee;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
        border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;      
    }
    
    .form-wrapper input:focus {
        outline: 0;
        background: #fff;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
        box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
    }
    
    .form-wrapper input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
       color: #999;
       font-weight: normal;
       
    }
    
    .form-wrapper input:-moz-placeholder {
        color: #999;
        font-weight: normal;
        
    }
    
    .form-wrapper input:-ms-input-placeholder {
        color: #999;
        font-weight: normal;
        
    }    
    
    .form-wrapper button {
  overflow: visible;
        position: relative;
        
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 40px;
        width: 110px;
        font: bold 15px/40px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
        color: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        background: #d83c3c;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
        border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;      
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
        top:-40px !important;
        margin-left: 373px;
    }   
      
    .form-wrapper button:hover{  
        background: #e54040;
    } 
      
    .form-wrapper button:active,
    .form-wrapper button:focus{   
        background: #c42f2f;    
    }
    
    
    
    .form-wrapper button:hover:before{
        border-right-color: #e54040;
    }
    
    .form-wrapper button:focus:before{
        border-right-color: #c42f2f;
    }    
    
    .form-wrapper button::-moz-focus-inner {
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

/*End of search style*/

/* post button*/
.post{
    height:5px;
}
.post button {
        overflow: visible;
        position: relative;
        
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 40px;
        width: 110px;
        font: bold 15px/40px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
        color: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        background: #d83c3c;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;      
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
        top:-49px !important;
        margin-left: 1100px;
    }

    .post{
        width: 100%
    }   
      
    .post button:hover{     
        background: #e54040;
    }   
      
    .post button:active,
    .post button:focus{   
        background: #c42f2f;    
    }
    
    
    
    .post button:hover:before{
        border-right-color: #e54040;
    }
    
    .post button:focus:before{
        border-right-color: #c42f2f;
    }    
    
    .post button::-moz-focus-inner {
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.svg" id="logo"></a>
    </div>


    <div id="search">
    <form class="form-wrapper cf">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Search here..." required>
 <button type="submit">Search</button>
 </form>
 </div>
 <div class="post">
 <button type="submit">POST</button>
 </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the code to plunkr or any other open code, where can edit and play around?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/VFA33I7TjJy2aYysZpBL?p=preview

Comment: what do you mean **the header**. what header?? there is not such thing as **THE** something

Answer (score 0):

You can use @media annotation in css, or you can use bootstrap framework.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /*For mobile or iPad*/
    .post {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong - it's already in the code and how will this fix `margin-left: 1100px;` on the button?

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of `css media queries`. If not i advice that you read on them (a simple google search would do). A media query consists of an optional media type and zero or more expressions that limit the style sheets' scope by using media features. You can use `media queries` to tell you `css` to display or rearrange certain things at certain screen sizes.

For example

```
.size {
    width: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 160px) and (max-width: 500px) {
    .size {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

This `query` would change `.size width` to `100%` if screen size is less than `500px` and revert back to `50%` if screen size is greater than `500px`

[read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

You could also try using responsive frameworks like

[bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)

Edited part of your code to show examples but its advisable you learn media queries.

**Your CSS**

```
    .navbar-fixed-top{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px red;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px red;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px red;
    background: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.1)
}

#logo{
    margin-top: -5px;
}

/*Search field*/
#search{

    font: 13px 'Lucida sans', Arial, Helvetica;
    color: #eee;
    text-align: center;
}

#search a {
    color: #ccc;
}

/*-------------------------------------*/

.cf:before, .cf:after{
  content:"";
  display:table;
}

.cf:after{
  clear:both;
}

.cf{
  zoom:1;
}

/*-------------------------------------*/   
/*EDITTED*/
.form-wrapper{
    height :50px;
    width: 100%;
}

/*EDITTED*/
.form-wrapper input {
    width: 500px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;    
    font: bold 15px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    border: 0;
    margin-left: 150px;
    background: #eee;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;      
}

.form-wrapper input:focus {
    outline: 0;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
}

.form-wrapper input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #999;
   font-weight: normal;
}

.form-wrapper input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.form-wrapper input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
}    

.form-wrapper button {
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;

    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 40px;
    width: 110px;
    font: bold 15px/40px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #d83c3c;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;      
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
    float: left;
}   

.form-wrapper button:hover{     
    background: #e54040;
}   

.form-wrapper button:active,
.form-wrapper button:focus{   
    background: #c42f2f;    
}



.form-wrapper button:hover:before{
    border-right-color: #e54040;
}

.form-wrapper button:focus:before{
    border-right-color: #c42f2f;
}    

.form-wrapper button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*End of search style*/

/* post button*/
.post{
    height:5px;
}
.post button {
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;

    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 40px;
    width: 110px;
    font: bold 15px/40px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #d83c3c;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;      
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
    top:-49px !important;
    margin-left: 80%;
}


.post{
    width: 100%
}   

.post button:hover{     
    background: #e54040;
}   

.post button:active,
.post button:focus{   
    background: #c42f2f;    
}



.post button:hover:before{
    border-right-color: #e54040;
}

.post button:focus:before{
    border-right-color: #c42f2f;
}    

.post button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**The Media Query**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 160px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .post {
        clear: both;
        margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: -45%;
    }
    .container-fluid {
        height: 120px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 160px) and (max-width: 900px) {
    .form-wrapper input {
        width: 300px;
        margin-left: 20%;
    }
    }
@media only screen and (min-width: 160px) and (max-width: 535px) {
    .form-wrapper input {
        width: 150px;
    }
    .form-wrapper button {
        width: 100px;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!--same as question-->
```

[image: Before Queries]

[image: After query on small screen]

Hope you get how this works

Comment: Yes , I heard of them ! But without using that my body is responsive. Is it possible for header with little change?

Comment: Alright let me take a look at your code for a moment

Comment: this is my full code : https://plnkr.co/edit/VFA33I7TjJy2aYysZpBL?p=preview

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you how `media queries` work

Answer (score 0):

Try with flex its easy to use, see my code its working for all devices

```css
* {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        outline: none;
        resize: none;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top{
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px red;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px red;
        box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px red;
        background: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.1)
    }
    .navbar-brand {
        display:inline-block;
    }
    
    /*Search field*/
    #search{
        font: 13px 'Lucida sans', Arial, Helvetica;
        color: #eee;
        text-align: center;
    }    
    .form-wrapper{
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        
        -webkit-box-flex: 2;
        -webkit-flex: 2;
        -ms-flex: 2;
        flex: 2;

        padding-left:10px;
        padding-right:10px;

        width:100%;
    }    
    .form-wrapper input {
        -webkit-box-flex: 2;
        -webkit-flex: 2;
        -ms-flex: 2;
        flex: 2;
        
        height: 40px;
        padding: 10px 5px;
        font: bold 15px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
        border: 0;
        background: #eee;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
        border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;      
    }    
    .form-wrapper input:focus {
        outline: 0;
        background: #fff;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
        box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
    }
    
    .form-wrapper input:-moz-placeholder,
    .form-wrapper input:-ms-input-placeholder,
    .form-wrapper input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: #999;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    .btn-style {
        overflow: visible;
        position: relative;
        
        border: 0;
        padding: 0 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 40px;
        font: bold 15px/40px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
        color: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        background: #d83c3c;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
        border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;      
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
    }
    .btn-style:hover{
        background: #e54040;
    } 
    .btn-style:active,
    .btn-style:focus{   
        background: #c42f2f;    
    }
    .btn-style:hover:before{
        border-right-color: #e54040;
    }
    .btn-style:focus:before{
        border-right-color: #c42f2f;
    }
    .btn-style::-moz-focus-inner {
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .container-fluid {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding:16px;
    }

    form {
        margin: 0;
        display:block;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .container-fluid {
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
            -webkit-box-direction: normal;
            -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 144px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" id="logo" width="100"></a>
        
        <form class="form-wrapper">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search here..." required>
            <button class="btn-style" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>

        <div class="post">
            <button class="btn-style" type="submit">POST</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```